# Node Puppeteer, missing module yargs

Tags: puppeteer

Node : 18.16.1
Puppeteer-code : 19.5.2
Puppeteer : 19.5.2

Cannot find module
node_modules@puppeteer\browsers\node_modules\yargs\package.json

I've tried to install
yargs@17.7.2

That doesn't seem to help.
What does this error instruct me to do?

I've tried to clear the npm cache to force a refresh of the package

I've also tried to delete the Node_Modules folder and npm i

I've tried installing the latest version of
Puppeteer : 20.7.4
Yargs : 17.7.1
As referenced here:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/fa412292be07a56f6a3e24ab1102fa62ff02b7b3/packages/browsers/package.json#L107

Answer (score 0):

I received this error message:

```
Cannot find modul
... 
node_modules@puppeteer\browsers\node_modules\yargs\yargs
...
node_modules@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\CLI.js
```

After a while, I realized that there was actually no file named `yargs` (without a file extension!!!) in my target directory. Ultimately, it was because I copied the Yargs directory using the wildcard `**/*.*` which naturally doesn't copy files without file extensions. The correct wildcard should have been `**/*`.
Maybe you made the same mistake.